# Are all the meta.* sites intended to be included in the data dump?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump

The April 2012 data dump included data for all SE sites, plus the associated `meta.*` sites. The August 2012 data dump does not include data for the `meta.*` sites, except that `meta.stackoverflow.com` is included.

Was this omission deliberate, or accidental? Can we expect to see the `meta.*` dump files return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meta sites were left out by accident - we are packaging a new torrent that includes just meta sites.  You can find it here:

http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2080-aug-2012-meta

Comment: Thanks Geoff, got it now.